# PostgreSQL: enable pg_stat_statements without server reload

Tags: configuration, postgresql, database, reboot

I'd like to enable extension `pg_stat_statements`. It was installed as an extension.
But I cannot see it until server is rebooted. Is there any way to avoid reboot? I tried:

1. `/etc/init.d/pg... reload`
2. `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgstatstatements.html):

> The pg_stat_statements module provides a means for tracking execution statistics of all SQL statements executed by a server.
>
> The module must be loaded by adding pg_stat_statements to shared_preload_libraries in postgresql.conf, because it requires additional shared memory. **This means that a server restart is needed to add or remove the module.**